# Как убрать верхний бордер и одновременно изменить цвет фона у TabBar в iOS 10+?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

Верхний бордер у tabbar убрать получается, но как одновременно с этим поменять цвет бэкграунда у таббара?

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        // делаем тайтлы красными:
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red

        // убираем верхний бордер:
        UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()

        // как сделать бэкграунд синим?
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue // не работает
    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. Вы установили пустую картинку в качестве `backgroundImage`, то просто задайте цвет фона:

```
UITabBar.appearence().backgroundColor = .blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте залить не прозрачной картинкой а цветной.

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(color: .blue)
```

Расширение для создания изображения залитого 1 цветом:

```
public extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```